# Rounding integers to nearest 5

Tags: bash, integer, rounding

Using the example below, anything below 2.5% will round down to 0%. How do I get it to round down to 1% and not 0%?

```
s='1.5% 2.5% 3.5% 25% 27% 34% 68%' 
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = int( ($i+2) / 5) * 5 "%"} 1' <<< "$s"
```

```
0% 0% 5% 25% 25% 35% 70%
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: after calculating the new `$i`, if the new value equals `0` then set to `1`; see the (`awk`) `if` and `ternary` operatiors

Comment: Try: `awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { n = int( ($i+2) / 5); $i = (n ? n * 5 : 1) "%"}} 1' <<< "$s`

Comment: @anubhava That did not work for anything above 3%, which no longer round to nearest 5.

Comment: @Cyrus Desired output is 1% 1% 5% 25% 35% 70%

Comment: @Shwing2345: It prints `5%` for `3%` which is 3rd number in list.